# php8 openssl openssl_cipher_iv_length returns 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a payment gateway for WordPress and it has below code to generate an encryption for bank:

```php
 private static function encrypt_tripledes($data, $secret)
{
    $method = 'DES-EDE3';
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $secret, 0, $iv);
    return $encrypted;
}
```

The problem is that `openssl_cipher_iv_length` returns 0 and the whole plugin & WordPress crashes when it wants to redirect to the bank payment website. how can I solve this problem?

Here is the error message when it wants to redirect to the bank:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Length must be greater than 0
```

Comment: The mode "DES-EDE3" is a synonym for Triple DES with **ECB mode** - ECB-modes in general do not use an IV so PHP/OpenSSL returns a zero length.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Thanks for your answer. But this exact code was working properly for a while and of a sudden, it breaks the whole system. I checked for every parameter that changes through updates and the only thing was the PHP version and WordPress version...

Comment: Maybe in older PHP versions the return was always "8" when the algorithm starts with "DES" and in newer ones they decided to return a "zero" when the algorithms points to an ECB mode.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Downgrading PHP version did not work as well :(

Comment: To say it in other words: PHP is running correctly as the encryption algorithm "DES-EDE3" means to use the DES algorithm in **ECB mode** - the ECB mode in general does not use or require an initialization vector, so PHP returns a length of "0" (means not required or necessary. You now have two choices: uses a mode that requires an IV (e.g. CBC mode) OR leave out the use of an IV.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I understand. thanks for your clarification.